# When does hibernate use its first level cache ? how to log it?

Tags: hibernate, caching, logging

Is there a simple way with hibernate log level to see when the first cache level is used or not ?

If I'm doing the following hql request : "from Document d left join fetch d.folder where d.id=2"; several time, in the same session, will the cache be used ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate L1 cache stores entities by primary key. This means that if you load the same entity using `load()` or `get()` (I think this also applies to simple queries like: `from Document d where d.id=2`)  it will be cached.

In your case the query is a bit more complicated and you will have to use L2. Unfortunately there is no logger indicating L1 activity (at least not [documented](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)) but seeing SQL queries shouls be enough.

## See also:

- [Caching with Hibernate + Spring - some Questions!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405417)

Comment: What about queries with a left join fetch on another entity ? thanks for the link

Comment: @Quentin: I believe you will have to fall back to L2 cache in this case.

Comment: Ok, do you know how can I log it (or which class is in charge of this cache), just to make sure ?

Comment: @Quentin: no, unfortunately, I am mentioning about L1 cache in my answer.